# Migrating Jenkins jobs from one server to another

Tags: jenkins

Copied Jenkins "jobs" directory from one A (VB) to server B (AWS). The jobs directory shows up in the server B with all the files in it. But those jobs doesn't populate in Jenkins UI. 
Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hit `/reload` URL on your Jenkins (it will ask you for login/pass naturally). This reads the configuration from XML files.

Comment: I did that. Restarted the jenkins as well. It doesn't show up. In fact, this Jenkins had one of the job with same name that's been copied from other server and even that job stopped showing after reload. What would be missing or going wrong?